# Simplest transaction does not get mined for hours - why?

Tags: homestead

I have a send transaction that is pending for the longest time. I quardupled the normal gas price, but still no results - probably it has something to do with ongoing spam attacks? Any other reason?

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe45cbefff7774cc51be1345bf5b1e08753611c86dfb25b7cdde4c361799030fe

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is related to the blockchain purge https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/5egco7/is_there_a_new_dos_attack_im_running_geth_152_and/dac8uly/